# Better way of structuring Spring circular dependency

Tags: spring-boot

I have a circular dependency I'm currently resolving with the

> @Lazy

Spring tag. But I'm wondering if there's a better way to resolve it through a redesign.

Basically I have 2 beans:

> 1. Scheduler Bean (schedules tasks based on schedule list)

> 2. ConfigGrabber Bean (gets a list of jobs from database and loads it into Scheduler as a schedule list), the first time being upon startup.

I need configGrabber to run every 10 min, I'm using scheduler to do schedule it to run.

This creates a bit of a circular reference between the two beans, since Scheduler, directly or indirectly, have to know about configGrabber. ConfigGrabber must know about scheduler. I am currently using a Factory class which knows about configGrabber with a @Lazy tag inside scheduler bean.

By using @Lazy, I'm essentially achieving:

1. scheduler bean inits, does not init configGrabber reference
2. configGrabber loads, calls scheduler
3. Scheduler indirectly calls configGrabber through the factory class
4. Spring injects configGrabber, which handles call.

This works, but this sequence seems unclean and not robust, is this design too confusing? Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: `Scheduler, directly or indirectly, have to know about configGrabber.` why?

Comment: The scheduler has to use the Factory class to create the Job to run configGrabber.

I know I can get configGrabber to create the job instead and pass it to scheduler. 


But it seems to me that configGrabber shouldn't know about the implementation of the scheduler. And it would have to pass a quartz job to the scheduler. Not to mention now instead of only being responsible for loading configs, configGrabber is also handling the creation of a scheduling job.

Comment: `The scheduler has to use the Factory class to create the Job to run configGrabber` why? scheduler should schedule tasks, what tasks are doing - it does not care